# SQL FORMAT function error

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

This SQL:

```
select FORMAT(lNum,'##-###-##-###') 
from  [rpt].[myView]
```

Produces the following error:

> Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 1 of format
>   function.

`lNum` is a `varchar(10)`

Running SQL Server 2012

Comment: Keep in mind, FORMAT can be an expensive function. See: [http://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but](http://sqlperformance.com/2015/06/t-sql-queries/format-is-nice-and-all-but)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`varchar` isn't supported as the first argument to `FORMAT`. The only categories of datatypes supported are `Date and Time` and `Numeric`.

You could do

```
select FORMAT(cast(lNum as numeric),'##-###-##-###') from  [rpt].[myView]
```

From levelonehuman's comment : [Documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx)

Comment: Instead of duplicating the answer, [FORMAT](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213505.aspx) on MSDN