# Format function is not working for one date in 2019

Tags: function, t-sql, format

```
SELECT FORMAT('2019-10-28 00:00:00', 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'ar-SA')
```

The above function is not working for this date alone. Any heads up?

When I change the year, this works.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL FORMAT function error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34094424/sql-format-function-error)

Comment: Can you throw more light on your comments please.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are trying to format a string, you have to convert it to a date (or datetime) first.

**Example**

```
SELECT FORMAT(try_convert(date,'2019-10-28 00:00:00'), 'yyyy-MM-dd', 'ar-SA')
```

Returns

```
1441-02-29
```

Comment: Why is this not working with only this date and year?

Comment: @Sirajudeen The major problem with your current attempt is that you were passing _text_ as the first parameter to `FORMAT`.  You can't do that.  The first parameter should be a datetime, q.v. John's answer above +1.

Comment: The above function is not working for this day alone. 
When I change the year, this works. So, this is not related to text format. If so, this function should throw this error for all the dates. It is not so.